# listing the null values with the group_concat in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$query4 = $db->query("SELECT count(codes.lcfruh) AS front_lcfruh, kw, datum,   GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name FROM codes 
RIGHT JOIN dienstplan ON (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh OR dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcteildienst OR dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcshteil) 
RIGHT JOIN personal ON personal.perso_id = dienstplan.perso_id 
WHERE personal.status_sum = 'rezeption' AND dienstplan.schicht!='' AND dienstplan.kw = '$kw' AND personal.zeigen='ja' 
GROUP BY dienstplan.datum");
```

I want to have a result of 7 input fields (for every day of the week). That works correct. Both fields with the 0 or value greate than 0 are listed, actually input field are created.

```
while ($result = $query4 ->fetch_object()) {
echo '<p class="taglist1"><input name="" type="text" title="'.$result->name.'" class="zbroj'.$result->front_lcfruh.'" value="'.$result->front_lcfruh.'"></p>';
}
```

In the title I want to have names listed if they have certain value, that is working also UNTIL I put the following line in the code in the `WHERE CLAUSE`

```
AND (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh OR dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcteildienst OR     dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcshteil)
```

The problem is the following in this case The result is not showing the fields that are not matching, where I should have the `count(codes.lcfruh)=0`. The fields that are not matching are not shown.

Is there a chance that I can put this line elsewhere in the code in order to get the null fields listed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you are putting into the `where` clause is:

```
AND (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh OR
     dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcteildienst OR
     dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcshteil
    )
```

Although you don't *intend* for this to be the case, this is also adding the conditions:

```
dienstplan.schicht is not null and
(codes.lcfruh is not null or dienstplan.schicht is not null OR dienstplan.schicht is not null)
```

Because `NULL` values are treated as false in the `where`.  This "undoes" the `right outer join`.

The solution is to move the conditions to the `on` clause.  Alternatively, you could add additional `or` clauses specifying that `NULL` is an ok value.

EDIT:

Try changing the `where` clause to:

```
AND (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh OR
     dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcteildienst OR
     dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcshteil OR
     dienstplan.schicht is null or
     (codes.lcfruh is null and codes.lcteildienst is null and codes.lcshteil is null)
    )
```

This will keep the rows that fail the `right outer join`.

EDIT II:

Next idea.  Move the condition to the `group_concat()`.  If the first query is working, then maybe this is what you want:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(case when dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh OR
                       dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcteildienst OR
                       dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcshteil
                  then ''
                  else name
             end)
```

If this doesn't work, then edit your question with sample data and desired results.

EDIT III:

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT count(case when personal.status_sum = 'rezeption' AND dienstplan.kw = '52'
                  then codes.lcfruh
             end) AS front_lcfruh,
       kw, datum,
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when personal.status_sum = 'rezeption' AND dienstplan.kw = '52'
                         then name
                    end) AS name
FROM codes
RIGHT JOIN dienstplan ON (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh)
RIGHT JOIN personal ON personal.perso_id = dienstplan.perso_id
GROUP BY dienstplan.datum;
```

I moved the conditions into the `select` statement, so all the rows would appear.

Comment: In which part of the code, can maybe write it down, i was trying but did not make it work

Comment: i did it but I am getting a list of everything in the table although I should have only 2 pieces of information. It is adding all the fields no matter what it is in it.

Comment: i have left the code as it first was and instead of GROUP_CONCAT(name) I have put your code but it does not work.

Comment: I have made an sqlfiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa4e3a/6, you will see that in the list are 5 results and there should be 7 for every day of the week (although 2 of them are NULL)

Comment: thanks a lot, I think you could have solved it earlier if I could have explained it a little bit better.